# trigonometric equations finding $x$, when $\cos(x)=0$ or some value

Tags: trigonometry

I'm practicing trigonometric equations where we need to find the value of $x$, however sometimes I keep getting a completely different solution than the one in the book and I don't really understand where I am making a mistake (and it's always in finding the $x$ in the end). For example:

Problem: $$\cos x  + \sqrt3\cos 2x + \cos3x=0$$ which gives: $$2\cos2x(\cos x + \frac{\sqrt3}{2})=0$$

and then:  $2\cos2x=0$ , where I get that $x=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{k\pi}{2}, k\in \Bbb Z$  
and:  $\cos x= -\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$, where I get $x=\frac{5\pi}{6}+ 2k\pi, k\in \Bbb Z$ (which based on my book is the only solution I got right) 
 
I believe I also have this: $\cos (2\pi - x)= -\frac{\sqrt3}{2} $, and the solution I got: $x=\frac{7\pi}{6}+ 2k\pi, k\in \Bbb Z$

I guess I'm getting something wrong since the solutions given are: 
  $x=\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2}$ ; $x=\frac{5\pi}{6}+2k\pi$; $x=-\frac{5\pi}{6}+2k\pi$, $k\in \Bbb Z$

Comment: From $\cos 2x=0,$ you have that $2x=\frac π2(2k+1),$ for any integer $k.$

Comment: $\frac{7\pi}{6}- \frac{-5\pi}{6}= \frac{12\pi}{6}= 2\pi$ so $cos\left(\frac{7\pi}{6}\right)$ is the same as $cos\left(\frac{-5\pi}{6}\right)$.

Comment: Your second solution of the other equation is equivalent to the given one, since $7π/6 = 7π/6-2π=-5π/6.$

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos(nx)=c$$ has the solutions

$$nx=2k\pi\pm\arccos(c)$$ or

$$x=\frac{2k\pi\pm\arccos(c)}n.$$

In the (frequent) event that $\arccos(c)$ is a rational fraction $\dfrac pq$ of $\pi$,

$$x=\frac{2kq\pm p}{qn}\pi.$$

In particular we have the special cases

- $c=-1\to\dfrac11\to \dfrac{2k\pm1}n\pi=\dfrac{2k+1}n\pi$,
- $c=0\to\dfrac12\to \dfrac{4k\pm1}{2n}\pi=\dfrac{2k+1}{2n}\pi$,
- $c=1\to\dfrac01\to \dfrac{2k\pm0}n\pi= \dfrac{2k}n\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

If $$\cos(2x)(\cos(x)\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})=0$$

then

$$\cos(2x)=0=\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})$$
or
$$\cos(x)=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}=\cos(\pi-\frac{\pi}{6})$$

then
$$2x=\pm \frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$$
or
$$x=\pm \frac{5\pi}{6}+2k\pi$$

The solutions are
$$\frac{\pi}{4}+k\frac{\pi}{2}\;,\;$$
$$ \frac{5\pi}{6}+2k\pi=-\frac{7\pi}{6}+2(k+1)\pi\;$$
and
$$\; \frac{-5\pi}{6}+2k\pi=\frac{7\pi}{6}+2(k-1)\pi$$

Answer (score 0):

If $-5\pi/6+2m\pi=7\pi/6+2n\pi$ where $m,n$ are arbitrary integers

$\iff m=n+1$

So, we have actually not missed anything

As $\cos(2r\pi\pm A)=\cos A,$

If $\cos B=\cos C,B=2p\pi\pm C$ where $r,p$ are Integers

Comment: sorry but If I got it right, then my solution is correct too?

Comment: @not, yes, but unconventional